# Hibernate: Entity changes in @PreUpdate callback are not persisted when lazy loading is active

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We are using Hibernate 5.2.17 in our project and populate the last modification date within a `@PreUpdate` entity callback.

After a lengthy debugging session it seems like that when

1. Bytecode enhancement for lazy loading is active
2. Multiple entity fields are loaded lazily

the changes done to the entity within the callback are *not* persisted on database level.

I was about to file this as bug for Hibernate, but before that get feedback on whether we do something wrong.

**Entity**

```java
@Entity(name = "Person")
private static class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private Instant createdAt;

    private Instant lastUpdatedAt;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<String> tags;

    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ByteBuffer image;

    @PrePersist
    void beforeCreate() {
        createdAt = Instant.now();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    void beforeUpdate() {
        lastUpdatedAt = Instant.now();
    }
}
```

**Test** (abbreviated)

```java
@Test
public void testPreUpdateModificationDate() throws Exception {
    EntityManager em = getOrCreateEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Person p = new Person();
    em.persist(p);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    int personId = p.id;
    em.refresh(p);

    p = em.find(Person.class, personId);
    assertNotNull(p);
    assertNotNull(p.createdAt);
    assertNull(p.lastUpdatedAt);

    p.name = "New Name";
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.merge(p);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    assertEquals(p.name, "New Name");

    em.refresh(p);

    p = em.find(Person.class, personId);
    // the last line fails
    assertNotNull(p.lastUpdatedAt);
}
```

As soon as the one of the lazily loaded attributes is removed from `Person`, the test runs successfully.

In debugging it looks like the SQL generation for an entity update does not consider the fields changed in `@PreUpdate` as dirty. The class `org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPersister` has a different SQL generation for "dynamic updates" which is chosen automatically when bytecode enhancement is active and more than 1 fetch group is present.

Comment: In the meanwhile I've opened a bug for Hibernate and they are looking into it https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in Hibernate in 5.3.3.

Bug report: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12718

Answer (score 0):

Works for me: not sure what is the issue, but you have many strange things. Perhaps start with this simple example and expand to your code to find the difference:

```
    tx.begin();
    Person p = new Person();
    em.persist(p);
    tx.commit();
    System.out.println(p);

    tx.begin();
    p.setName( "New Name" );
    tx.commit();
    System.out.println(p);
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Your basic test works for me as well. My test only fails on the last line. As soon as I remove one of the lazily loaded fields (like `image`or tags`) my test works completely. Besides that I'd like to know what the strange things are that I have. I just removed the unnecessary `flush` statements.

Comment: Well, why are you doing `refresh`? Your entities are not out of sync with the database. And why are you doing `merge`? You just read the entity from the database so its state is not inconsistent. My point in the above code was that you are using JPA incorrectly and from what I can tell JPA/Hibernate is working fine.

Comment: got your concern. in fact that's not productive code, but just a test to isolate the bug and to demonstrate that the value set in preupdate is eventually not persisted.

In the meanwhile I've opened a bug for Hibernate and they are looking into it: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12718